# Where does the fuel that the mid-air refueling probe collects go to?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, mid-air-refueling, fuel-systems

Where does the fuel that a mid-air refueling probe collects go to? Does it go straight to the engine, to the fuel injector(s), or does it go to some place that then sends the fuel somewhere?

Comment: Since it's a *refueling probe*, wouldn't you expect it to feed into one or more of the fuel tanks on the receiving plane?

Comment: Are you asking about the part that the fuel plane sticks out or the part that the plane that is refueling has?

Comment: @DanPichelman On a really basic level, yes.  But the probe itself doesn't go strait into the tank, generally.  It goes into an intake device (as show in aeroalias diagram), which will deliver it to a fuel tank.

Comment: If it went straight to the engines I'd be extremely worried about the speed at which fuel is being used! Flagging as low quality. I asked my very much non-aviation/engineering mother this question and got the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fuel coming in through aerial refueling probe goes into the aircraft fuel tanks just like the ground fueling. The schematic below shows the fuel system of the F-16.

[image: F-16 fuel system]

F- 16 fuel system; image from [f-16.net](http://www.f-16.net/forum/download/file.php?id=14481&t=1)

As can be seen, the aerial refueling system's fuel load goes into the same one as the ground refueling one, through the same lines. Another thing is that in case external fuel tanks are connected, they can be topped up first (they are depressurized once aerial refueling commences and fuel transfer from them stops) before the internal tanks are filled up.

The fuel goes to the center-line(fuselage) or the wing tanks, from where it goes into the reservoir tanks, which supplies to the engine, just like 'regular' fuel.

Answer (score 0):

To the fuel tanks, presumably.